# Expression Engine relationship field checkbox

Tags: field, relationship, expressionengine, controlpanel

I am working with Expression Engine 2.1 and would like to have a relationship field that links one channel to another. This works fine for a one to one relationship but I want a many to many. It does a many to one by default. I would like check boxes instead of a drop-down menu.

Is this possible out of the box or do I need a third party plugin to do this.

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a third-party add-on like [Playa](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/playa). There are others as well, but Playa is the best-raed and most-established.

Comment: Thanks for the response. By chance do you know if there are any free alternatives or possible work arounds that don't involve palya?

Comment: An inexpensive alternative is [The Selectatron](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/the-selectatron) ... or you could write your own fieldtype and spend far more than the $75 that Playa costs! But there are no workarounds I'm afraid ... EE's built-in relationship fieldtype is one-to-many only.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at The Selectatron